Strapi api doesn't return image field
I'm in a pretty strange situation.
the url /api/home-page?populate=* doesn't return my image field
but /api/home-page?populate=heroImage does
On the other side I have another single page very similar where populate=* and populate=heroImage are both working fine.
What can explain that problem?
Below the two schema.json
home-page :
{
  "kind": "singleType",
  "collectionName": "home_pages",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "home-page",
    "pluralName": "home-pages",
    "displayName": "Page d'accueil",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "seo": {
      "type": "component",
      "repeatable": false,
      "component": "shared.seo"
    },
    "heroImage": {
      "type": "media",
      "multiple": false,
      "required": false,
      "allowedTypes": ["images"]
    },
    "img": {
      "allowedTypes": ["images"],
      "type": "media",
      "multiple": false
    }
  }
}

the other page :
{
  "kind": "singleType",
  "collectionName": "ou_trouver_bonuxes",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "ou-trouver-bonux",
    "pluralName": "ou-trouver-bonuxes",
    "displayName": "Où trouver Bonux"
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "heroImage": {
      "allowedTypes": [
        "images"
      ],
      "type": "media",
      "multiple": false
    }
  }
}


With the populate=* parameter, it returns first-level relations, components and dynamic zones.
You can use Strapi deep populate plugin. Install the plugin
npm i strapi-plugin-populate-deep

and make the requests like
/api/articles?populate=deep


Thank you. But, what I'm trying to understand is why the heroImage field if returned on a route and not the other as they have the same configuration. I guess I'm missing something somewhere
